# How to get correct encoding with groovy HtmlParsing from a website?

Tags: html, groovy, character-encoding

I am making a Groovy script where i'm html parsing a swedish website and I want to get the swedish characters Å, Ä and Ö back from the site.

This is an example of what i'm trying to do (not the actual site i'm scraping in my project but an example).

When i run the script below it gives me the output "Avancerad s�kning" when i really want "Avancerad sökning".

Does anyone know how to do this encoding in a good way?

```
@Grab(group='org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup', module='tagsoup', version='1.2' )

String page= "http://www.webhallen.com/se-sv/"

def tagsoupParser = new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser()
def slurper = new XmlSlurper(tagsoupParser)
def htmlParser = slurper.parse(page)

htmlParser.'**'.findAll { it.@class?.text() == 'first-child' }.each {println it.toString()}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but it works with nekohtml:

```
@Grab('net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.21')

String page= "http://www.webhallen.com/se-sv/"

def tagsoupParser = new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()
def slurper = new XmlSlurper(tagsoupParser)
def htmlParser = slurper.parse(page)

htmlParser.'**'.findAll { it.@class?.text() == 'first-child' }.each {println it.toString()}
```

Comment: Oh Nice! That was easy :). 
Thank you so much!